# How to remove specific string in a file using find & sed

Tags: linux, shell, centos, find, cpanel

All my index.php were injected with

```
<script type='text/javascript' src=’https://www.example.com/home?v=2.2.0′></script>
```

at the 1st line of it.

So I want to just remove that particular line `"<script type=’text/javascript’ src=’https://www.example.com/home/public′></script>"` via Terminal in Cpanel running CentOS

I do some research and I have came up with this :

```
find . -name “index.php” -exec sed -i “s#<script type=’text/javascript’ src=’https://www.example.com/home?v=2.2.0′></script>##g"; {} +
```

The terminal shows an error :
find: missing argument to `-exec'
bash: {}+: command not found

Comment: First of all, correct your quotations marks. Some are non-ASCII (e.g. “).

Answer (score 2):

You've just ended your line too fast! The `;` should be at the end of the line.

```
find . -name index.php -exec sed -i "s#<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.example.com/home'></script>##g" {} +;
```

(be careful, there some quotes/anti quotes or typographic quotes in your example... it could be confusing)

But I see 2 informations in your question (first line + a pattern).

The easiest way (not the only one), wouldn't be to **delete the first line of all the index.php** files?

If so, just use:

```
find . -name index.php -exec sed -i '1d' {} +;
```

You also can use `for` instead of `exec`:

```
for i in `find . -name index.php`; do sed -i '1d' $i; done;
```

On macOS/freeBSD style, just add `''` in `sed`:

```
for i in `find . -name index.php`; do sed -i '' '1d' $i; done;
```

If you are looking to delete an entire pattern, you will need to protect special chars and so on, and **you will need to be careful not to delete, for example, the same but useful pattern at any other place in your files**. So be careful.

Comment: Yes this is great. However, my first line do involved "<?php" after the <script></script> tag though. My bad for not posting a whole code here.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that's because you are using hash character `#` as regex delimiter.
My personal favorite there is using at sign `@` for the same, thus:

```sh
find . -name 'index.php' -exec sed -i "s@<script.*example.com.*</script>@@" {} \;
```